# Bloc Delegate : Classes can only extend other classes. Try specifying a different superclass, or removing the extends clause

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

**I was upgrading my flutter_bloc to version:**

```
  flutter_bloc: ^7.0.0
```

from

```
  flutter_bloc: ^3.2.0
```

but now it seems that the BlocDelegate class doesn't seems to work and ,i am stuck on this  problem

> Here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class SimpleBlocDelegate extends BlocDelegate {
@override
void onEvent(Bloc bloc, Object event) {
print(event);
super.onEvent(bloc, event);
}

@override
void onError(Bloc bloc, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
print(error);
super.onError(bloc, error, stackTrace);
}

@override
void onTransition(Bloc bloc, Transition transition) {
print(transition);
super.onTransition(bloc, transition);
 }
}
```

is there a solution to it or should i downgrade ?

My flutter version :

Flutter 2.2.0 • channel stable •

Framework • revision b22742018b (2 weeks ago) • 2021-05-14 19:12:57 -0700

Engine • revision a9d88a4d18

Tools • Dart 2.13.0

Answer (score 3):

In bloc 7.0.0 you can access this api using the BlocObserver class
Instead of extending from BlocDelegate the class Should Extend from BlocObserver.

```
class SimpleBlocObserver extends BlocObserver {
  @override
  void onCreate(BlocBase bloc) {...}

  @override
  void onEvent(Bloc bloc, Object event) {...}

  @override
  void onChange(BlocBase bloc, Object? event) {...}

  @override
  void onTransition(Bloc bloc, Transition transition) {...}

  @override
  void onError(BlocBase bloc, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {...}

  @override
  void onClose(BlocBase bloc) {...}
}
```

You can read more about BlocObserver in https://bloclibrary.dev/#/coreconcepts?id=blocobserver

Comment: Change to BlocObserver like I answered above and pay attention to the BlocBase class in some of the functions instead of Bloc as parameter

Answer (score 0):

From the [migration page](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration?id=%e2%9d%97blocdelegate-renamed-to-blocobserver):

> BlocDelegate renamed to BlocObserver